struct tm pointer works not stable
I'm not very good at English, so please bear with me.
[Code 1] Sometimes the result is -0(wrong), and sometimes is 62726400(correct).
[Code 2] The result is always 62726400(correct).
Why the code 1 is not stable?
How can I improve code 1?
// Code 1
time_t timer2;
struct tm *t2 = (struct tm*)malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
t2->tm_year = 1997 - 1900;
t2->tm_mon = 9 - 1;
t2->tm_mday = 14;
timer2 = mktime(t2);

time_t timer3;
struct tm *t3 = (struct tm*)malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
t3->tm_year = 1995 - 1900;
t3->tm_mon = 9 - 1;
t3->tm_mday = 19;
timer3 = mktime(t3);

double diffA = difftime(timer2, timer3);
printf("%.f\n", diffA);

// Code 2
printf("When struct tm is not pointer\n");
time_t timer4;
struct tm t4 = {0};
t4.tm_year = 1997 - 1900;
t4.tm_mon = 9 - 1;
t4.tm_mday = 14;
timer4 = mktime(&t4);

time_t timer5;
struct tm t5 = {0};
t5.tm_year = 1995 - 1900;
t5.tm_mon = 9 - 1;
t5.tm_mday = 19;
timer5 = mktime(&t5);

double diffB = difftime(timer4, timer5);
printf("%.f", diffB);

I try the different way to allocate memory:
struct tm *t2 = (struct tm*)malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
and
struct tm *t2 = malloc(sizeof(*t2));
However, the result of the two way is same(not stable).

If you #include <stdlib.h> the cast to the result of malloc() is redundant. If you don't #include <stdlib.h> the cast tells the compiler to shut up and not report the error of (in its view) assigning an int to a pointer. In the absence of a prototype, the compiler "thinks" malloc() returns an int.

There are two problems:

In the first version, you leave all fields that you not explicitly set uninitialized which means they will carry indeterminate values. In the second version you zero-initialize the struct tm before assigning values.
The tm_isdst field should be set to -1 in both versions unless you know that daylight saving time was not in effect for the supplied time points.

You can fix the first problem by using calloc instead of malloc:
struct tm *t2 = calloc(1, sizeof *t2);

Or, you could make sure the whole struct tm is initialized by assigning a fully initialized object to it using a compound literal with designated initializers:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t timer2;
    struct tm *t2 = malloc(sizeof *t2);
    *t2 = (struct tm){            // (struct tm) { ... } is a compound literal
        .tm_year = 1997 - 1900,   // .tm_year is a designated initializer
        .tm_mon = 9 - 1,
        .tm_mday = 14,
        .tm_isdst = -1
    };
    timer2 = mktime(t2);

    time_t timer3;
    struct tm *t3 = malloc(sizeof *t3);
    *t3 = (struct tm){
        .tm_year = 1995 - 1900,
        .tm_mon = 9 - 1,
        .tm_mday = 19,
        .tm_isdst = -1
    };
    timer3 = mktime(t3);

    double diffA = difftime(timer2, timer3);
    printf("%.f\n", diffA);
    
    free(t2);
    free(t3);
}

